# Evaluating the arithmetic intensity of a for loop

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel-processing

I am parallelizing the execution of the following loop on a CUDA GPU:

```
// define m, lp, N

for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
    float p, s;
    int q;

    s = m + sqrt( ARR1[ ARR2[i] ] )*ARR3[i];

    if ( ARR4[2*i] <= ARR10[i] ){
        if ( s > 0){
            p = lp*s;
            q = floor( ARR4[2*i+1]*ARR5[i]/p );
        } else{
            p = -lp/s;
            q = -floor( ARR4[2*i+1]*ARR6[i] );
        }
    } else{
        if ( s > 0){
            p = lp/s;
            q = -floor( ARR4[2*i+1]*ARR6[i] );
        } else{
            p = -lp*s;
            q = floor( ARR4[2*i+1]*ARR5[i]/p );                 
        }
    }

    if ( q != 0){
        ARR7[i] = p;
        ARR8[i] = q;
    } else{
        ARR7[i] = 0;
        ARR8[i] = 0;
    }
    ARR9[i] = i;
}
```

I would like to evaluate its arithmetic intensity. `m` and `lp` are defined outside of the loop.

I count 11 memory operations: `ARR2[i]`, `ARR1[ARR2[i]]`, `ARR3[i]`, `ARR4[2*i]`, `ARR4[2*i+1]`, `ARR5[i]`, `ARR6[i]`, `ARR7[i]`, `ARR8[i]`, `ARR9[i]`, `ARR10[i]`,

... and 9 floating-point operations (counting `floor` and `sqrt` as one FLOP each): `m + sqrt( ARR1[ ARR2[i] ] )*ARR3[i]` (3), `p = lp*s` or variations (1), `q = floor( ARR4[2*i+1]*ARR5[i]/p )` or variations (5, including 2 for index calculation).

Since all array elements are 4-bit long, this gives me an arithmetic intensity of **`9/(4*11) = 0.2045`**. Is this correct? Am I counting memory and arithmetic operations correctly? In particular, I'm unsure whether the index array calculation `2*i+1` should count towards the FLOP count, and whether the scalar values `m` and `lp` should count towards the data movement count (or are they kept in registers and therefore do not count, see [AXPY example on p. 16 here](http://www.int.washington.edu/PROGRAMS/12-2c/week3/joo_03.pdf).

Comment: I could run it through the profiler, but this is more of a didactic example to make sure I understand how to calculate arithmetic intensity.

Comment: The profiler indicates that the loop has an intensity of `1.92` (ratio of arithmetic operations to memory operations), but I don't see how this number is obtained.

Comment: You can't tell anything by looking at a stanza of uncompiled C code. This requires dissassembly of assembler output and analysis of individual instructions.